# how to filter down to frequent words in text and omitting non frequent words in matlab

Tags: matlab

i am extracting words from text file along with there frequencies in the text on the basis of there occurrences, i am getting all the words along with there frequencies with the following statement:

```
freq = [num2cell(counts.') words.']
```

but this statement outputs all the words with there frequencies(counts) like follows:

```
[1]    '1980s'         
[1]    '1993'          
[2]    'AI'            
[1]    'After'         
[1]    'And'           
[1]    'Another'       
[1]    'Artificial'    
[1]    'Ask'           
[1]    'Asked'         
[2]    'Ballmer'       
[8]    'Bayesian'
```

what i want to do is to show only words whose frequencies are greater than or equal to 3 like as follows:
[8]    'Bayesian' 
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to make `counts` a cell array.  Simply use it to determine those counts that are `>= 3`, then index into your `words` array:

```
out_words = words(counts >= 3);
```

`out_words` should contain those words where the counts are `>= 3`.

However, if you also want to display the frequency beside the word like how you're displaying it in your post, simply find those locations that are `>= 3`, then index into each of `counts` and `words`:

```
ind = counts >= 3;
freqs = [num2cell(counts(ind).') words(ind).']
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works fine but i want to display number of times(frequency/counts) along with words just as if i do freq(counts>=3) it only shows out put as [3][8][6] but the words are not displayed.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad - That's pretty easy.  I'll update my post.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad - Done. Have a look.